# Excel VBA Regression Analysis - Expected Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, regression

Attempting some VBA code to use regression analysis to find the relationship between employee tenure, gender and salary. The VBA code I have written is not working due to a Compile Error: Expected Array

The following is the code I have used - any pointers greatly received!

```
Sub RegressionAnalysis()

'Define variables
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim chart_ws As Worksheet
Dim chart_obj As ChartObject
Dim xRange As Range
Dim yRange As Range
Dim genderRange As Range
Dim idRange As Range
Dim lr As Long

'Set worksheet and range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:D11")

'Set X and Y range
Set xRange = rng.Columns("C")
Set yRange = rng.Columns("D")
Set genderRange = rng.Columns("B")
Set idRange = rng.Columns("A")

'Create linear regression analysis
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinearRegression(yRange, xRange)

'Output regression results
MsgBox "The regression equation is y = " & lr(1) & "x + " & lr(2) & "." & vbCrLf & _
"The R-squared value is " & lr(3) & "."

'Create scatter plot
Set chart_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ws)
Set chart_obj = chart_ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Chart

With chart_obj
    .SetSourceData Source:=rng
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Salary vs. Tenure by Gender"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Tenure"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Salary"
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 1
    .HasLegend = True
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xRange
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yRange
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "All Employees"
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleTriangle
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 5
    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xRange, 0, 1) * (genderRange = "Female")
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(yRange, 0, 1) * (genderRange = "Female")
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Female Employees"
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 7
    .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xRange, 0, 1) * (genderRange = "Male")
    .SeriesCollection(3).Values = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(yRange, 0, 1) * (genderRange = "Male")
    .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Male Employees"
    .SeriesCollection(3).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
    .SeriesCollection(3).MarkerSize = 7
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        .SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
        .SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = idRange.Cells(i).Value
    Next i
End With

'Cleanup
Set rng = Nothing
Set xRange = Nothing
Set yRange =
```

Comment: You define `lr` as a `Long` and later try to use it like it's an `Array` and it's not an `Array`.

Comment: There is no Worksheet function `LinearRegression`. Do you mean `WorksheetFunction.LinEst`?